# Error comparing SGD+momentum v/s SGD on MNIST

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working on a toy project to compare the performance of SGD and SGD+momentum optimizers on MNIST data. To do this, I have created 2 cell blocks, one for SGD:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0)
for epoch in range(10):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0
```

Loss after 10 epochs for SGD : loss: 0.674

I've then created another cell for SGD+momentum:

```
sgd_momentum = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.7)

for epoch in range(10):
    #similar as in SGD, just replace the optimizer
```

The problem I'm facing is that SGD+momentum is trying to optimize from the point where SGD left off. This is the loss for the first minibatch, epoch 1:

[1,  2000] loss: 0.506

How do I ensure that SGD+momentum takes the original loss? I am unable to understand the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, once optim.step() has been used, the weight optimization begins automatically (provided no other flags have been set).

Calling model = model() / Net() before using the second optimizer did the trick, as it reinitialized the network